# How to copy a JSON document inside another using jq

Tags: json, wrapper, jq

How can I transform a JSON document like this:

```
{ "foo": 123, "bar": "abc" }
```

into something like this:

```
{ "payload":  { "foo": 123, "bar": "abc" } }
```

using the command line tool `jq`?

Comment: jqplay can help : https://jqplay.org/s/-PqIuXgXD0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to wrap an object around the input.

```
jq '{payload: .}' some.json
```